# Can't animate letters (wrapped with span tag) inside the DIV with jQuery animate method

Tags: jquery, dom

```
var letter = $("div#text").children().first();
letter.animate({
    opacity:"0.5"
},3000) // works!


var allLetters = $("span");
allLetters[1].animate({
    opacity:"0.5"
},3000) // it doesnt works
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n40af9dh/

When I invoke an animation method on the letter variable which holds an inference to the span object through jQuery traverse DOM method: $("div#text").children().first() it works. However, when I invoke the same method on:

```
var allLetters = $("span");
allLetters[1].animate({
    opacity:"0.5"
},3000)
```

it doesnt works and console outputs the following error:

> Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not
>   supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because accessing a jQuery object by an index (as you are with `[1]`) returns a DOMElement which does not have an `animate()` method, hence the error.

To do what you require you should use `eq()` instead:

```
$("span").eq(1).animate({
    opacity: 0.5
}, 3000);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wp9p4swy/)

Note that the item at index `1` is the second `span` as indexes are zero based. If you want the first span, use `eq(0)`.

Comment: As alternative you can also wrap `allLetters[0]` in a `$()` like: `$(allLetters[0])`

Comment: That's bad practice as it's entirely redundant code though. You're getting a DOMElement from a jQuery object just to turn it back in to a jQuery object again.